# Overriding Block class causes constructor err in magento 2

Tags: error, magento2.2.6, compiler

I want override a block class, for this I have made entry in di.xml using preference and created a respective file on my custom module block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct. My file is calling but now here apart from modify other functions I also need to modify  __construct() function of base class. But I don't know how to do it

---

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product;
//use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

 class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {

      protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = Toolbar::class;

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var AbstractCollection
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var PostHelper
     */
    protected $_postDataHelper;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $urlHelper;
    protected $request;
    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;
    //        public function __construct(
    //     \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    //     PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    //     Resolver $layerResolver,
    //     CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    //     Data $urlHelper,
    //     Http $request,
    //     array $data = []
    // ) {
    //     $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    //     $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    //     $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    //     $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    //     parent::__construct(
    //         $context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$request,$data);
    // }

    public function initializeProductCollection(){
        echo "stringjhhj";
        echo $categoryId = $this->request->getParam('myselection'); // all params

            $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator())->getId());
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
             $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
             var_dump( $category);die;
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
               echo $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
        var_dump($collection->getData());

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        //$this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );

        return $collection;
        }

        public function  _getProductCollection(){
    // make changes here means call MyinitializeProductCollection in place of initializeProductCollection
            if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
        }

        public function getLoadedProductCollection(){
            // make changes here means call _MygetProductCollection in place of _getProductCollection
           // die("jhsjf");
        return $this->_getProductCollection();

        }
}
```

di.xml

---

**Update :**

Error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context given, called in
>   /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/generated/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct.php:55
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/generated/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(14):
>   Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper),
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver),
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data), Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magen in
>   /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct.php
>   on line 55

Comment: Can you update the error to your question? Also post the di.xml as well.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct::__construct() must be an instance of Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\Context, instance of Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context given, called in /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/generated/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /var/www/html/trainees/pooja_new/Magento22/app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Rewrite/Product/ListProduct.php:55 Stack trace:

Comment: di.xml                                                                                                      
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct"/>

Comment: Try to compile : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: i did but nothing happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {

      protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = Toolbar::class;

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var AbstractCollection
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var PostHelper
     */
    protected $_postDataHelper;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $urlHelper;
    protected $request;
    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        Data $urlHelper,
        Http $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        parent::__construct($context,$postDataHelper,$layerResolver,$categoryRepository,$urlHelper,$data);
    }


    public function initializeProductCollection(){
        echo "stringjhhj";
        echo $categoryId = $this->request->getParam('myselection'); // all params

            $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator())->getId());
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
             $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
             var_dump( $category);die;
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
               echo $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
        var_dump($collection->getData());

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        //$this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );

        return $collection;
    }

    public function  _getProductCollection(){
    // make changes here means call MyinitializeProductCollection in place of initializeProductCollection
            if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection(){
            // make changes here means call _MygetProductCollection in place of _getProductCollection
           // die("jhsjf");
        return $this->_getProductCollection();

    }
}
```

Finally run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy if needed and test.

Comment: [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\Context does not exist      
  Class Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor ge  
  neration error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the   
  'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bi  
  n/magento setup:di:compile'

Comment: as i am giving the permission but still it is not taking and give this error ,even i deleted both var and generated folder but not working

Comment: Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: yes it is problem of context

Comment: Updated one not working? I have changed the context path?